# Margin/Padding resizing with rem

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the font-size of my root element to change the overall font-sizes, margins, and paddings.

The thing is when I change the html tag's `font-size` it will change the fonts all perfectly but the margins and paddings stay the same as if `1rem = 10px`

Here's a pen that shows what I mean:

http://codepen.io/Spittal/pen/xewqh/

-HTML

```
<div class='container'>
  <h1>Hello! REM!</h1>
  <p>Hello Paragraph REM!</p>
</div>
```

-CSS

```
html { 
    font-size: 61.5%;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 3rem;
  margin: 3rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

If you try changing the `font-size` of the html element and you'll see that it changes just the font-sizes not the margins or paddings.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It seems to be working in your pen. Margins and paddings look pretty proportional to the font-size.

Comment: Works fine for me too.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Hey! so I'm doing some more drastic changes and it does seem to change the margin and padding slightly, but I'm not understanding why it's changing the values like it is. for example and font-size of 10% computes the padding and margin to be 27px; as opposed to the 30px computed when it's at 62.5%. This isn't the scaling I was expecting, any reason why?

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at your codpen and found that the margin and padding sizes do actually change.

Take a look a these two screenshots from Chrome page inspector:

[62% font size](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_dm_cPSM1oFSVR3Z1pOb1VnVkE/edit?usp=sharing)

[63% font size](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_dm_cPSM1oFdnhvZHlxNy1XQnM/edit?usp=sharing)

Hope this sheds some light on things!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working fine in chrome.

This could have to do with the browser you are using to check it.

You can insulate your css to default a set `px` if the browser does not support.

A good example of what you are trying to do is this,

```
body { font-size: 12px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.one, .two {
  border: solid #666;
  border-width: 10px; border-width: 0.01rem;   /* 1vw */
  border-radius: 30px; border-radius: 0.03rem; /* 3vw */
  font-size: 20px; font-size: 0.02rem;         /* 2vw */
  padding: 20px; padding: 0.02rem;             /* 2vw */
}
```

Please refence here for more information, [Here](http://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing/)